# asp.net C# - set roles in web.config for subdirectory

Tags: security

```
**After login i am not able to access page.After login again redirect to login page.
```

I am using two level of folder structure. CMS folder contain two folder.
   1. User.
   2. Admin.

```
 ---CMS
     ----User
     ----Admin
Means CMS/{USER}{Admin}.**
```

> In main web.config

In main web.config i am set loginurl and allow all user.

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="HESCMS1.0" loginUrl="~/CMS/User/Login.aspx" timeout="40" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" protection="All" requireSSL="false" enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
  </system.web>
```

> In User folder web.config:

Set role for admin user

```
 <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="CMSUserAdmin" />
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  <location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
```

> In Admin folder web.config:

Set role for super admin.

```
 <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="CMSSuperAdmin"/>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  <location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

This is my first post in stack so have not so much experience.